# How can I get test coverage for a Visualforce controller?

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller

with this test class I have a coverage of 0% someone has an idea why it does not work
I can not recover the id of the product it seems that it is not inserted

```
public with sharing class ControllerOppRel {

    public Product2 opptyList;
    public ControllerOppRel (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    opptyList = (Product2)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public List<OpportunityLineItem> getOpprel(){
    return [SELECT Id, Product2Id, OpportunityId,Opportunity.Name,Opportunity.StageName,Opportunity.Account.Name, TotalPrice FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2Id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

    }
}
```

test class:

```
@isTest
private class TestControllerOppRel {

        @testSetup Static void setup(){
        Account acc=new Account(name='lacost');
        insert acc;
        Product2 prod=new Product2(name='support');
        insert prod;
        Opportunity opp=new Opportunity(Name='optest',CloseDate=date.newInstance(2019,9, 21),StageName='new',Account=acc,Numero_chassi__c='12345678909876543',Pricebook2Id='standard');
        insert opp;
        OpportunityLineItem oppline=new OpportunityLineItem(Opportunity=opp,Product2=prod,TotalPrice=5000,UnitPrice=400,Quantity=2);
        insert oppline;
        system.debug('testoppo  '+opp);

         }

    @isTest static void testCont(){
    Product2 prod = [SELECT id FROM Product2 LIMIT 1];

        PageReference pageRef = Page.OpportoProduct; // OpportoProduct my PVF

        pageRef.getParameters().put('Id', String.valueOf(prod.Id));

        test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        Apexpages.StandardController sc = new Apexpages.StandardController(prod);       

        ControllerOppRel ext = new ControllerOppRel(sc);

        List<OpportunityLineItem> opl=[SELECT Id, Product2Id, OpportunityId,Opportunity.Name,Opportunity.StageName,Opportunity.Account.Name, TotalPrice FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2Id=:prod.id];
        system.assertEquals(opl, ext.getOpprel());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern I use to pass parameters in tests is this:

```
    Test.setCurrentPage(Page.Payees);
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('bop', '1');
```

I suggest you change to this and see what happens.

You can check to see if the product is inserted by doing e.g.:

```
Product2[] prods = [SELECT id FROM Product2 LIMIT 1];
System.assertEquals(1, prods.size());
Product2 prod = prods[0];
```

Comment: Hi Keith C thank you for the answer i think that the product was not attached to the opportunity

Comment: @Anirbas Cool. When you have confirmed, post the answer yourself so people know not to look into this further.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your valuable help this solution works

```
@isTest
private class TestControllerOppRel {

        @testSetup Static void setup(){
        Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
        Account acc=new Account(name='lacost');
        insert acc;
        Product2 prod=new Product2(name='support',Family = 'Hardware');
        insert prod;
        PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(
        Pricebook2Id = pricebookId, Product2Id = prod.Id,
        UnitPrice = 10000, IsActive = true);
        insert standardPrice;

        // Create a custom price book
        Pricebook2 customPB = new Pricebook2(Name='Custom Pricebook', isActive=true);
        insert customPB;
        // 2. Insert a price book entry with a custom price.
        PricebookEntry customPrice = new PricebookEntry(
        Pricebook2Id = customPB.Id, Product2Id = prod.Id,
        UnitPrice = 12000, IsActive = true);
        insert customPrice;

        Opportunity opp=new Opportunity(Name='optest',CloseDate=date.newInstance(2019,9, 21),StageName='new',Account=acc,Numero_chassi__c='12345678909876543');
        insert opp;
        OpportunityLineItem oppline=new OpportunityLineItem(Product2Id=prod.id,OpportunityId=opp.id,Quantity=2,PricebookEntryId=customPrice.id,TotalPrice=5000);
        insert oppline;
        system.debug('testoppo  '+oppline);


         }

    @isTest static void testCont(){
        Product2[] prods = [SELECT id FROM Product2 LIMIT 1];
    //Product2 prod = [SELECT id FROM Product2 LIMIT 1];
        System.assertEquals(1, prods.size());
        Product2 prod=prods[0];
        PageReference pageRef = Page.OpportoProduct; // OpportoProduct my PVF
        pageRef.getParameters().put('Id', String.valueOf(prod.Id));
        test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        Apexpages.StandardController sc = new Apexpages.StandardController(prod);       
        ControllerOppRel ext = new ControllerOppRel(sc);
        List<OpportunityLineItem> opl=[SELECT Id, Product2Id, OpportunityId,Opportunity.Name,Opportunity.StageName,Opportunity.Account.Name, TotalPrice FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2Id=:prod.id];
        system.assertEquals(opl, ext.getOpprel());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the test in Developer Console? If so, take a look at the log entry that's created by the test (the top one, if you look immediately after testing). There you'll get some hints as to what went wrong. Try filtering for 'Error'.

That being said, try

```
OpportunityLineItem oppline=new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId=opp.Id,Product2=prod,TotalPrice=5000,Quantity=2);
        insert oppline;
```

(Set OpportunityId ; only give TotalPrice or UnitPrice).

Also, I recommend running each test method on its own, so you can fix each one individually.

Comment: thank you tiruman it works